# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myplguin_admin_page' not found or invalid function name

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding a new page to wordpress-menu.But it is giving me the error:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'myplguin_admin_page' not found or invalid function name.

What is that I am missing?

**plugin.php**

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_admin_menu' );

function my_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'My Top Level Menu Example', 'VENDOR RATE UPDATE LOG', 'administrator', 'tested.php', 'myplguin_admin_page', 'dashicons-tickets', 6  );
}
```

**tested.php**

```
function myplguin_admin_page(){
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Welcome To My Plugin</h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Is tested being included properly by wordpress? It says the function does not exist, looks like it has issues including it.

Comment: yes it is in the same directory @César

Comment: But is it included? I'm not sure how the Wordpress procedure of including files is, but if you add require_once 'tested.php'; to the beginning of plugin.php you should be able to see if it's an issue with including the file.

Comment: r: Cannot redeclare my_admin_menu()  when i add require_once 'tested.php'; @César

Comment: Those are not the complete files I suppose then. Because that error wouldn't come up there if they were.

Comment: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/creating-wordpress-admin-pages/?hpv=b&utm_expid=3606929-74.aeX0WyvtRVa7qMe8Ph5smw.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F i am using this link as refrence @César

Comment: Have you checked that the file name are the same ones he proposes in his gists? If you take a close look next to his code samples there are file names which do not map to yours at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this answer will help you, but I'm putting it here for the community.

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by changing the name of the function with this code:

```
array(__CLASS__,'myplguin_admin_page')
```

So the line will be finally:

```
add_menu_page( 'My Top Level Menu Example', 'VENDOR RATE UPDATE LOG', 'administrator', 'tested.php', array(__CLASS__,'myplguin_admin_page'), 'dashicons-tickets', 6  );
```

Hope that helps anybody with that issue too.

Comment: Error is fixed but the callback function is still not running now...

Answer (score -1):

The solution is  we have to include both files in plugin.php file
separtely

```
require('top-level.php');
require ('simple-page.php');
```

Moreover there is syntax error in simple-page.php in the given link